# Compiling the sample GDK applications

Tags: google-gdk

I followed the directions (OSX, Eclipse Juno) and created the new android sample project.
Project got created, but the R wasn't generated and I wasn't able to build and run the application due to errors in the code. I tried to clean and build but no success. Every other aspect of the instructions worked well. DDMS perspective detected the glass device and the build target is Glass Development Kit Sneak Peek.

I also tried to open the project in Android Studio 0.3.6 but no luck.

Any help generating the R would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are there any messages in your Console or Problems view that indicate problems with running the Android build tools?

Comment: There are 27 errors: "R cannot be resolved to a variable" and one import error in line "import com.google.android.glass.sample.compass.R;"

Comment: Often time when R wasn't generated was due to some sort of build error. Double check to ensure there were any other errors that might trigger the build to fail.

Answer (score 0):

No idea whether this will work well, but worked for me.

Delete all the Glassware projects with errors. Close Eclipse and restart it. Now create a new project with a "new name" which is not similar to the previous projects. While creating, make sure the Minimum and Target SDK are android 4.0.3. "Compile with" should be "Glass Development Kit". Now insert you code, import any missing packages and save it.

I did the same and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same steps on my Windows work computer, and the R generated just fine.
So, guessing this is a Mac+Eclipse issue.